# Shared Memory - Process communication

Tags: c, shared-memory

**What I have to do:**
-Create a shared memory segment.
-fill an array with a fixed number of integers e.g 100
-pass these created numbers to a child process in blocks of 10 each.
-in the child process: output these numbers
So this is basically a communication between two processes via a shared memory segment.

**My question**: So far I can pass the first 10 numbers to the child process .. but I don't really know how to pass the next 10 numbers to the very same child process to output it without creating more child processes .. I thought maybe I could simply wrap everything in a while loop but then everytime a new child process is created which is not what I want.

Right now I have the following Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N_SHARED 10
#define SIZE 100

int main(int argc, char **argv){
int shID;
int *myPtr;
int i;
int counter = 0;

int array[SIZE];
for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
array[i] = lrand48();
}

/* Shared Memory Creation */
    shID = shmget(223520, N_SHARED, IPC_CREAT | 0666);

    if (shID >= 0) {
        /* get memory */
        myPtr = shmat(shID, 0, 0);
        if (myPtr==(int *)-1) {
            perror("shmat");
        } else {
            /* memory is accessible */
                for (i=0; i<N_SHARED; i++) {
                    myPtr[i] = array[counter];
                    counter += 1;
                }  

                // create Child Process
                pid_t child = fork();

                if(child == 0){
                    sleep(5);
                    shID = shmget(223520, N_SHARED, 0666);
                    if (shID >= 0) {
                        myPtr = shmat(shID, 0, 0);
                        if (myPtr==(int *)-1) {
                            perror("shmat");
                        } else {
                            for (i=0; i<N_SHARED; i++) {
                                printf("%d\n", myPtr[i]);
                            }
                        shmdt(myPtr);
                        }
                    }else { 
                        /* shmget went wrong */
                        perror("shmget");
                    }   
                }


                /* give up memory */
                shmdt(myPtr);
        }
    } else { 
    /* shmget went wrong */
    perror("shmget");
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to use some other type of synchronisation such as a semaphore. This is just a classic producer-consumer problem. Go do a search on that.

Comment: the posted code continues to execute when some (critical) system call fails.   I.E. each call to `perror()` should be followed by the statement: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`